# How to register route in router.module as a child route

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

I have a following app structure:

```
/app
  /administration
    /useradmin
      useradmin.module
      useradmin.routing.module

    administration.module
    administration.routing.module
```

currently, each module registers it's own routes:

**administration.routing.module:**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'administration', component: AdministrationComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }])
```

**useradmin.routing.module:**

```
RouterModule.forChild([
  { path: 'administration/user', component: UserComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }])
```

How do I modify the routing modules so that routes defined in useradmin.routing.module will be child routes of "administration" route?

Answer (score 0):

Update  **administration.routing.module** to:

```js
RouterModule.forChild([
    {
        path: 'administration',
        component: AdministrationComponent,
        children: [
            {path: 'user', component: UserComponent}
        ]
    }
]);
);
```

More detailed info is provided here
https://angular.io/guide/router#child-route-configuration

Answer (score 0):

you can use `LazyLoad` for modules.

In you `main route` module in `app.module`

```
  {
    path: 'administration',
    loadChildren: () => import('./administration/administration.module').then(mod => mod.AdministrationModule),
  },
```

Then in your `administration.routing.module` you must declare routes like this

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: AdministrationComponent,
      },
       {
    path: 'useradmin',
    loadChildren: () => import('./useradmin/useradmin.module').then(mod => mod.UseradminModule),

  },
];

  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Then in `useradmin.routing.module` you declare useradmins routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
  }];
```

and in module add `RouterModule.forChild(routes),`

Comment: Yeah, the problem is, that `administration.routing.module` must be aware of 'useradmin' route. Ideally I would like to have this route defined in `useradmin.routing.module`

Comment: Then in useradmin.routing.module you declare useradmins routing

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
  }];
and in module add RouterModule.forChild(routes),

Comment: I don't see what is different in the comment from the answer version